# How to manage screen scrollview and collectionview scrollview same time in ios/xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

On one screen,I am having some content and below that having collectionview,so I want to know how to manage scrollview of screen and scroll of collectionview.I cant make disable collectionview scroll bcoz I am using paging for collectionview on DecelerationEnded delegate method,So for that I ahve to use scroll of collectionview.
So,please give me solution that how to mange these two scrollview same time because screen is not responsing for two seconds.

Comment: Show some code, What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can put tag(self.scrollView.tag = XXX) for the scroll view and put conditions in the delegate methods.